# Octobercms with bootstrap 5 error on compiler "expecting list, null received:......."

Tags: sass, octobercms, bootstrap-5

I use Octobercms and bootstrap 5 Alpha2. I try to compile bootstrap 5 scss files with build in octobercms compiler like this:

```
<link href="{ ['assets/vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss']|theme }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but on frontend i get error:

```
expecting list, null received: /.../.../.../themes/octobercms/assets/vendor/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss on line 8, at column 5 Call Stack: #0 mixin generate-utility /.../.../.../themes/octobercms/assets/vendor/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_api.scss on line 13 #1 function breakpoint-min.......
```

If i disable bootstrap 5 utilities/_api.scss, compiler works ok, but then i don't get any utilities classes.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error.

It is caused by themes that bundle outdated versions of SCSSPHP, which is the engine the performs the compilation of SCSS to CSS under the hood.

You can resolve it by downloading the latest version of [scssphp](https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/), locating the old embedded version in your theme, and replacing it.